# Firebase Real-time database rules. Get rules without @uid in url

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Need to set rules for Realtime Database to check the field `user` for compliance with `auth.uid`. Can you do it like that?

Routine check

```
"tasks": {
   "$uid": {
       ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
       ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
}
```

These rules don't work, and check `auth.uid =! null` same.

[image]

Comment: you need to modify your push code to insert tasks->UID. Currently as per your image it is inserting Unique key, which is different then uid https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: Did @Grimthorr's answer solved your problem ? Otherwise can you show your query not working ?

Comment: @Curse yep, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to match the `user` value in your database to the current user's UID. In your example, however, it looks like you've mixed up the task ID and the user ID.

You need to use the security rules [`data` variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables) to match your `user` child node to `auth.uid`. To do that, your rules will need to look something like:

```
"tasks": {
    "$task_id": {
        ".read": "data.child('user').val() == auth.uid",
        ".write": "data.child('user').val() == auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Using `$task_id` will create a [capture variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) to match any path segment under `tasks`, but the actual value of this isn't used in the instance. Instead, we obtain the value of the child node at `tasks/$task_id/user` and compare this to the `auth.uid` by using `data.child('user').val()` in the read & write rules.

Further reading on all valid rule variables and some examples can be found in the [securing your data documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

Comment: and links should look like this? site.com/ -LPqa516TxYFFw-JJOQi /tasks ? this url is soo long

Comment: It would be the other way around: `example.com/tasks/-LPqa516TxYFFw-JJOQi`, but that's a different question.